# angular.copy vs plain javascript array slice

Tags: arrays, angularjs, deep-copy

In angularjs, when I need to deep-copy an array, which is better between:

```
var newArray = angular.copy(oldArray);
```

and

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice();
```

Comment: .slice is still shallow copy I think. or you really really need deep copy?

Comment: *"when I need to deep-copy an array"* - slice is not deep.

Comment: Basically, I am looking to copy an array by value. I am not sure if I want deep copy or shallow copy. Both methods seem to work.

Comment: if array contains numbers or string, it is copy by value, in slice, but if you copy array of objects, those objects are just copy by reference with slice. if you dont need that, you are ok with shallow copy.